# How can I check if a string contains characters stored in an array but return false if it contains any characters not in the array

Tags: php, arrays

Basically I'm checking days of the week from an array to a string based on an initialization of the day for instance:

```
<?php
$check_days = array("M", "T");
$days1 = "MTW";
$days2 = "M";
[insert code to compare $check_days to $days1 and $days2 so that $days1 returns FALSE while $days2 returns TRUE]
?>
```

Comment: Sorry guys, something has come up and I have to tend to it immediately. I'll try your solutions and mark the appropriate solution when I return. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using a regex [character class](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.character-classes.php) and [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php):

```
if (preg_match('/^['.implode($check_days).']+$/', $days1)) {
    // do some stuff
}
```

**EDIT:** Let me help explain what's going on here:

```
implode($check_days)
```

This combines all the elements of an array into a single string. In your case, this is "MT".

```
preg_match('/^[MT]+$/', $days1);
```

This is a [regular expression](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.introduction.php) that checks that after the 'beginning' (`^`), `$days1` contains either an "M" or a "T" (`[MT]`), repeated one or more times (`+`), then the string ends (`$`). It returns true if this is the case.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I haven't ignored you. I'm just trying to wrap my head around whats going on here. reading documentation.

Comment: No. Matches `'MMMMMWWWWTTTT'`, as well.

Comment: @PHPglue I'd be happy to amend the answer if OP further requests that characters not repeat. As it stands, I just provide an example of "return false if it contains any characters not in the array"

Comment: I'm really sorry to get back so late (life happened) but this is just what I needed. Repeating will not happen because the variables are coming from a database with a standardized format. Thanks for teaching me a new function!

Comment: @GarrettBlackmon It's really no problem at all :) many people ask questions and forget about them altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function checkDays($testFor, $inString){
  $a = str_split($inString); $d = array();
  foreach($a as $v){
    if(!in_array($testFor, $v) || in_array($d, $v)){
      return false;
    }
    $d[] = $v;
  }
  return true;
}
$check_days = array('M', 'T');
echo checkDays($check_days, 'MTW');
echo checkDays($checkdays, 'M');
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I read your question wrong, and so my answer is wrong too. I'd go with wavemode's solution.

**Original answer**

If I understand your requirements correctly, you want to make sure all the days in `check_days` must exist in the variable to be tested. If I'm correct, this function will work:

```
function checkDays($haystack, $validator) {
    $ok = true;
    foreach ($validator as $day) {
        $ok = (strpos($haystack, $day) !== false) && $ok;
    }
    return $ok;
}
```

See it in action in this phiddle: http://phiddle.net/6